# Git lab preparing CI scripts to deploy automatically to server in yii2?

Tags: yii2, gitlab

Here is my `readme` file to installation.I want to merge it on  server using Ci in gitlab.

### Installation

- Clone project from Gitlab

```sh
git clone --single-branch --branch branchname https://gitlab.com/project/project.git
```

- Update needed libraries

```sh
cd project
composer update
```

- Go to project root directory cloned above and initialize all the configuration files which will be added to the application with a specific environment.  Enter `Yes` to all the overwrite files (`[Yes|No|All|Quit]`)

```sh
php init --env=Development
```

- Create a new database, copy the file named `common/config/main-local.example` to `common/config/main-local.php` and adjust the `components['db']` configuration in `common/config/main-local.php` accordingly.

```sh
cp common/config/main-local.example common/config/main-local.php
nano common/config/main-local.php
```

- Change mail configuration inside `common/config/main-local.php`
- Get `Recaptcha` keys (v2) from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin
- Copy the param file named `common/config/params.example` to `common/config/params.php` and adjust the configuration in `common/config/params.php` accordingly.

```sh
cp common/config/params.example common/config/params.php
nano common/config/params.php
```

- Apply migrations which will create tables needed for the application to work. Enter `Yes` to all prompts to dev environment but take extra care on the production environment (so it run the migrations and add the database tables to your db)

```sh
php yii migrate
```

- Create assets folder under backend/web , allow group users to change the content and make the directory owned by apache user

```sh
mkdir -p backend/web/assets
chmod 775 backend/web/assets
sudo chown www-data:www-data backend/web/assets
```

> What should be in the .gitlab-ci.yml file and ci/docker_install.sh
>   ,ci/shell-scripts-dev.sh,ci/shell-scripts-prod.sh. Please also explain
>   how it work?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Have a look if you have time.I have learned about docker.But this is my first experience to work with git lab and docker.Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
#
# File is "indented" using multiple of 4 spaces
#
# Specify the docker image to use (only used if using docker runners)
# See: http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html
# From https://hub.docker.com/r/kaffineaddict/gitlabcakephp3/ - we could use  image: kaffineaddict/gitlabcakephp3
image: php:7.2

# The docker services to configure
# See: http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-service
services:
    #- mysql:5.7

# Define custom build variables
#   For the default gitlab variables see: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html
#   These can be used below, or they will also be ENV variables available within' any scripts
#   you execute from the CI
variables:
    #MYSQL_DATABASE: site_zoova
    #MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "1"
    #MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ThisIsAStrongPassword#^2

# Define commands that run before each job's script
before_script:
    - umask 022 # set permissions to default directory permissions of 755 and default file permissions are 644,
    # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
    # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    #- docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli

    # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

    # For Docker builds disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
    # you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
    # WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
    # you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

    # Prepare the build environment. A way to overcome this is to create a script which installs all prerequisites prior the actual testing is done.
    - bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null
    #- bash ci/docker_install.sh
    # Prepare the build environment. A way to overcome this is to create a script which installs all prerequisites prior the actual testing is done.
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR && curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

    # Install composer dependencies
    #- composer install --no-plugins --no-scripts
    #- cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR && php composer.phar config cache-files-dir /cache/composer
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR && php composer.phar install --no-plugins --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR

    # Folder and file manipulation
    - 'which rsync || ( apt-get install rsync -y )'
    - '[ -d $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/web/assets ] || mkdir -p $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/web/assets'
    ## please change this line to the cache directories of yii mvc
    # - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/tmp/*
    - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/web/assets/*
    - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/runtime/debug/*
    - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/runtime/logs/*
    - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/runtime/mail/*
    - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/runtime/URI/*
    #   Rest runtime files
    - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/rest/runtime/cache/*
    - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/runtime/debug/*
    - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/runtime/logs/*
    - rm -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/runtime/mail/*


    - find $CI_PROJECT_DIR -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
    - find $CI_PROJECT_DIR -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
    - chmod -R 777 $CI_PROJECT_DIR/backend/web/assets
    - chmod +x $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ci/*
    - chown www-data:www-data $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ -R
    # Make sure these dirs/files are not writable

    # setup application
    - chmod go-w $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    #run code sniffer
    - php ./vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php backend --colors
    - php ./vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php common --colors
    - php ./vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php rest --colors
    #- |
        # following will done once on the server
        # cp common/config/main-local.example common/config/main-local.php
        # cp common/config/params.example common/config/params.php
        # cp rest/web/index.example rest/web/index.php

        # genetraing files and added to z_rsync_exclude_list
        #php ./init --env=Development --overwrite=All

        # replacing credentials in config file
        #sed -i "s/{APP_DB_HOST}/${APP_DB_HOST}/g" ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/common/config/main-local.php
        #sed -i "s/{APP_DB_NAME}/${APP_DB_NAME}/g" ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/common/config/main-local.php
        #sed -i "s/{APP_DB_USERNAME}/${APP_DB_USERNAME}/g" ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/common/config/main-local.php
        #sed -i "s/{APP_DB_PASSWORD}/${APP_DB_PASSWORD}/g" ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/common/config/main-local.php

        # updating composer for dependencies
        #php composer.phar update

        # running yii migrations 
        #yes | php yii migrate

        # resolve errors through phpcs
        #php ./vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php backend --colors
        #php ./vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php common --colors
        #php ./vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php rest --colors

        # making required directories & assigning permissions
        #mkdir -p backend/web/assets
        #chmod 775 backend/web/assets
        #chown www-data:www-data backend/web/assets
    #- |
# Define commands that run before after all builds
after_script:
    #- find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \; # Set directory permissions #moved in each stage
    #- find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \; # Set file permissions #moved in each stage


# Define list of files that should be cached between subsequent runs -
# Composer stores all downloaded packages in the vendor/ directory.
# temporary commented out - builds failed
cache:
    paths:
        - vendor/

# stages is used to define build stages that can be used by jobs
# The specification of stages allows for having flexible multi stage pipelines
# The next stage only executes if all elements of the previous stage succeed
# Typically used for compiled languages testing and/or to automate deployments
stages:
    - development
    - production

#
# Run test on all branches but master
#
development:
    stage: development
    only:
        - dev
    script:
        - echo Running dev
        # DO NOT COPY THIS KEY TO PUBLIC PLACES
        - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV")
        #- echo Running tests...
        # Ex: - phpunit --configuration phpunit_myapp.xml
        #- vendor/bin/phpunit # TODO: uncomment me - in docker file we have it as /usr/local/bin/phpunit
        # Sync the files to the server
        - echo Using rsync to push changes to dev server...
        - rsync -ap --stats -e "ssh -p $SSH_PORT_DEV" --exclude-from 'ci/z_rsync_exclude_list.txt' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ $SSH_USER_DEV@$SSH_IP_DEV:$PROJECT_PATH_DEV
        - echo Running shell scripts on remote server
        - ssh -t -p $SSH_PORT_DEV $SSH_USER_DEV@$SSH_IP_DEV 'cd '"'$PROJECT_PATH_DEV'"';ci/shell-scripts-dev.sh'
        # Done
        - echo Done pushing changes to dev...
        #Environment is used to define that a job deploys to a specific environment. This allows easy tracking of all deployments to your environments straight from GitLab.
        #If environment is specified and no environment under that name exists, a new one will be created automatically.

    environment: development
        #Make sure we don't push to live if build has failed
    allow_failure: false #default behaviour

#
# Send to live server if branch is master
#
production:
    stage: production
    only:
        - master
    script:
        - echo Running prod
        # DO NOT COPY THIS KEY TO PUBLIC PLACES
        - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PROD")
        #- echo Running tests...
        # Ex: - phpunit --configuration phpunit_myapp.xml
        #- vendor/bin/phpunit #TODO: uncomment me - in docker file we have it as /usr/local/bin/phpunit
        # Push to live server now
        - echo Using rsync to push changes to live server...
        - rsync -ap --stats -e "ssh -p $SSH_PORT_PROD" --exclude-from 'ci/z_rsync_exclude_list.txt' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ $SSH_USER_PROD@$SSH_IP_PROD:$PROJECT_PATH_PROD
        - echo Running shell scripts on remote server
        - ssh -t -p $SSH_PORT_PROD $SSH_USER_PROD@$SSH_IP_PROD 'cd '"'$PROJECT_PATH_PROD'"';ci/shell-scripts-prod.sh'
        # Done
        - echo Done pushing changes to live...
    #Environment is used to define that a job deploys to a specific environment. This allows easy tracking of all deployments to your environments straight from GitLab.
    #If environment is specified and no environment under that name exists, a new one will be created automatically.
    environment: production
    ##make sure development built before moving to production
    dependencies:
        - development
```

Here you `ci/docker_install.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
# I had to specify DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive as we get after install apt-utils: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
# We need to install dependencies only for Docker
[[ ! -e /.dockerenv ]] && [[ ! -e /.dockerinit ]] && exit 0

set -xe

# add the add-apt-repository command
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install software-properties-common -y

# Install git (the php image doesn't have it) which is required by composer
apt-get update -yqq
#debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#apt-get install git -yqq
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install apt-utils git zip unzip -y
# Here you can install any other extension that you need
#docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql intl mcrypt soap
docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```

Here your `ci/shell-scripts-dev.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
#do not enter current dir
#cd $(dirname $0)
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
printf "\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
printf "# Running dev script from directory  #\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
pwd

printf "\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
printf "# Create initial/ needed files  #\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
# backend init files
if [ ! -f backend/config/main-local.php ]; then
    printf "File backend/config/main-local.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp backend/config/main-local.example backend/config/main-local.php
fi

if [ ! -f backend/config/params.php ]; then
    printf "File backend/config/params.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp backend/config/params.example backend/config/params.php
fi
if [ ! -f backend/web/index.php ]; then
    printf "File backend/web/index.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp backend/web/index.example backend/web/index.php
fi
if [ ! -f backend/web/index-test.php ]; then
    printf "File backend/web/index-test.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp backend/web/index.example backend/web/index-test.php
fi
# common init files
if [ ! -f common/config/main.php ]; then
    printf "File common/config/main.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp common/config/main.example common/config/main.php
fi

if [ ! -f common/config/main-local.php ]; then
    printf "File common/config/main-local.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp common/config/main-local.example common/config/main-local.php
fi

if [ ! -f common/config/params.php ]; then
    printf "File common/config/params.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp common/config/params.example common/config/params.php
fi


# rest init files
if [ ! -f rest/config/params.php ]; then
    printf "File rest/config/params.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp rest/config/params.example rest/config/params.php
fi
if [ ! -f rest/web/index.php ]; then
    printf "File rest/web/index.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp rest/web/index.example rest/web/index.php
fi
if [ ! -f rest/web/index-test.php ]; then
    printf "File rest/web/index-test.php does not exist, creating it, please edit configuration on server!\n"
    cp rest/web/index.example rest/web/index-test.php
fi
printf "\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
printf "# Clearing cache #\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
# backend runtime files
rm -rf backend/web/assets/*
rm -rf backend/runtime/debug/*
rm -rf backend/runtime/logs/*
rm -rf backend/runtime/mail/*
rm -rf backend/runtime/URI/*
rm -rf cache/*
# rest runtime files
rm -rf rest/runtime/cache/*
rm -rf backend/runtime/debug/*
rm -rf backend/runtime/logs/*
rm -rf backend/runtime/mail/*


###############################################################################
# Rebuild assets# - don't we need this???
###############################################################################
#chmod +x ../app/Console/cake
#cd ../app && Vendor/bin/cake asset_compress build --force

printf "\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
printf "# Composer update #\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
php composer.phar install

printf "\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
printf "# Running yii migrations #\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
yes | php yii migrate

printf "\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
printf "#Run PhpSniffer and output any errors #\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
php ./vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php backend --colors
php ./vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php common --colors
p
```

hp ./vendor/bin/phpcs --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php rest --colors

> Note: You can configure these configration file on server yourself or
>   replace with example files.Working like cham

Answer (score -1):

1 / You need to access the server using ssh, then do the following:

a / gitlab-runner register

`sudo gitlab-runner register`

b / edit the .gitlab-ci.yml file :

```
stages:
- sit
deploy_linxsit:
stage: sit
variables:
APP_SIT_FOLDER: "/home/project_name"
- echo "Deploying code to SIT server"
- echo "rsync code from $CI_PROJECT_DIR to $APP_SIT_FOLDER"
# rsync only updated and new files, delete file if it's longer in repo need recursive flags
#       also exluced file/dir included in excluded_list.txt
- rsync -ur --delete --exclude-from "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/excluded_list.txt" "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/" "$APP_SIT_FOLDER"
tags:
- "fill tag when register gitlab-runner"
environment:
name: "SIT"
url: http://domain/project_name
only:
# only deploy changes on branch sit, for example when merging branch branch to branch sit
- sit
```

Comment: @not related at all